# Node.js cloud functions using Tensorflow graph

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I trained a deep-learning model with python using Tensorflow library, and I saved it in pickle file.

My question- Is there a way to extract this file with firebase cloud functions via node.js runtime?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There has been an official javascript version of tensorflow released some weeks ago.

With tfjs-converter it is possible to convert pretrained models to javascript.

Check out https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter and https://js.tensorflow.org/

Comment: Thank you for sharing. As you explained, applying tfjs-converter, it is as simple as the following code:

    import * as tfc from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
    import {loadFrozenModel} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter';
    const MODEL_URL = 'https://.../The_model.pb';
    const WEIGHTS_URL = 'https://.../weights_manifest.json';
    const model = await loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);